# will react manage the state without redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

How to manage the state in **React** without using **Redux** and **Hooks**. Is there any new concept is there?

Comment: You can simply google `react state` and find the answer, and it is at the front part of react documentation. Maybe that is not exactly what you are looking for, and if that is the case, the question needs to be more specific.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) I also recommend Jon Skeet's [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). You'll notice that three people have downvoted the question. I can't be absolutely sure, but I figure it's probably because of lack of research. The React documentation talks about managing state quite a lot, and there are countless non-Redux examples on the web (and here on SO).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can manage state without redux, see [State and Lifecycle](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html) in the documentation. If you're using hooks, you mostly use [`useState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate) ([more here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html)). If you're writing class components, you use the `state` property and [`setState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate).